# How to use Exoplayer inside view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider, exoplayer

I need to create an auto slider of images and videos

where I have used `viewpager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for changing the fragments. Inside the fragments I have used `exoplayer` where I play video when the fragment is visible and release the resource once the video play is complete.

It is working as expected if there are more than 3 videos or images. But if there are only 2 videos then it shows black screen for the second video. How to clear the `exoplayer` instance before changing the fragment?

Comment: any solution yet?